# How to login in private browser with FOSuserbundle?

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I just started using symfony and fosuserbundle to handle users, so i want to konw how to login in private browser even if you are logged in from normal browser ?
So i want to login with two different users one in normal browser and other in private browser.
Thanks a million for your help.

Answer (score 0):

> So i want to login with two different users one in normal browser

You have to distinguish session cookie value somehow. If you sign in with "normal" and other account in "private" - this will work.

But it's impossible to have two different users on the same session and under equal domain path.

Create another private session (depends on browser; some of them shares cookies between another windows while some nope) or separated "normal" browser profile or use another browser or set your site to be hosted with two different (sub)domains.

There are - probably - an another method but requires to modify your application.

Comment: i am a total newbie, so can you please tell me how to do it or guide me to usefull resource where i can lear about it

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/690/how-can-i-get-a-new-browser-session-when-opening-a-new-tab-or-window-on-firefox